# Obter dados de google analitycs em tempo real

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api

Estou tentando integrar a API do google para obter os user's ativos no site.

Alguém consegue dar 1 ajudinha? não estou a conseguir obter resultados, nem erros.

**NOVO CODIGO COM SDK GOOGLE**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require 'vendor_2/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;

/**
 * TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
 *   property ID before running the sample.
 */
$property_id = '333966316';

// [START analyticsdata_initialize]
// Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
// specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=Teste Final-27c88128db22.json');


$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
// [END analyticsdata_initialize]

// [START analyticsdata_run_report]
// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'city',
        ]
    ),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);
// [END analyticsdata_run_report]

// [START analyticsdata_run_report_response]
// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
    // [END analyticsdata_run_report_response]
    
    var_dump($row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue());
}
```

Comment: editei o código da pergunta, com o SDK do google para PHP, mas mesmo assim não estou obter resultados nem erros.

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa criar as credenciais no Google Cloud Console, em APIs e serviços > Credenciais > Contas de serviço.

Recomendo você utilizar o SDK para PHP pelo composer [google/analytics-data](https://packagist.org/packages/google/analytics-data), pois irá facilitar tanto na confirguração da autenticação quanto nas chamadas aos serviços.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: editei o código da pergunta, com o SDK do google para PHP, mas mesmo assim não estou obter resultados nem erros.

Comment: Estou utilizando exatamente desta forma, a única diferença é na passagem das credenciais para o client. Tente instanciar o client com `$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient(['credentials' => 'Teste Final-27c88128db22.json']);` 

Porém como não há erro, acredito que a autenticação esteja correta. A propriedade informada possui dados no período solicitado?